# Experimental PCL 1.7 with ROS fuerte

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when i follow the commands from the website:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ERROR

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[ 16%] Building CXX object io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/src/image_grabber.cpp.o
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp: In member function ‘bool pcl::ImageGrabberBase::ImageGrabberImpl::getCloudVTK(size_t, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Quaternionf&) const’:
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:634:34: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud_color.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGBA::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = timestamp’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:634:34: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note: ros::Time& ros::Time::operator=(const ros::Time&)
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:670:28: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = timestamp’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:670:28: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note: ros::Time& ros::Time::operator=(const ros::Time&)
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp: In member function ‘bool pcl::ImageGrabberBase::ImageGrabberImpl::getCloudPCLZF(size_t, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Quaternionf&, double&, double&, double&, double&) const’:
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:765:34: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud_color.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGBA::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = timestamp’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:765:34: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note: ros::Time& ros::Time::operator=(const ros::Time&)
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:810:28: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = timestamp’
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:810:28: note: candidate is:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note: ros::Time& ros::Time::operator=(const ros::Time&)
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:169:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
make[2]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/src/image_grabber.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Can someone understand what's the problem? Waht should I change?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65145/experimental-pcl-1.7-with-ros-fuerte/) by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jan_w](https://answers.ros.org/users/4495/jan_w/) on 2013-06-14**:
It seems as if the current repository status is not being able to be build. Take a look at (not enough karma...). Google for build.pointclouds.org/overview.html

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-24**:
(karma!?) I googled but nothing usefull. Can you be more precise?

**Comment by [Jan_w](https://answers.ros.org/users/4495/jan_w/) on 2013-06-24**:
I just figured out that you can directly c&p the following into the addressbar of your browser: build.pointclouds.org/overview.html then, below the login button, there is a link "login as guest". That will lead you to an overview of the buildfarm of pcl, where the status of all repos is listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Checkout pcl17 and pcl17_ros packages as suggested by others. Linekd the libfiles and now I get this message.

[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minitof_listener.dir/src/main.o
In file included from /home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/io/pcd_io.h:43:0,from /home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/minitof_listener/src/main.cpp:3:
/home/crops_laszlo/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/include/pcl-1.7/pcl17/point_cloud.h:46:27: fatal error: Eigen/StdVector: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/minitof_listener.dir/src/main.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/minitof_listener.dir/all] Error 2

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

---

Originally posted by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) with karma: 46 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-25**:
You need:
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})